# Symbolic link in rescue mode in centos

Tags: linux, centos-7

I accidentally deleted /bin the symbolic link.

Now, I can not log in to the machine. ln command is not available in grub
How can I fix the symbolic link in grub?

Answer (score 0):

Boot with the kernel options `rw init=/usr/bin/sh`.

When you get to the shell, use `/usr/bin/ln -s usr/bin /bin`.

(You might need `/usr/bin/mount -o remount,rw /` if the root filesystem is still read-only at this point.)

Afterwards don't forget to `sync` before rebooting.